# How do you configure elastic search marvel to send its data to different cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-marvel

I've heard the suggestion that marvel should write its data to a different cluster than its monitoring.  Makes sense because if your production cluster goes south so does your monitoring.

Can anyone point me in the direction of where the steps are to do this?

Thanks
-Doug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Each node from your monitored cluster should have this in the configuration:

  `marvel.agent.exporter.es.hosts`

set to a list of nodes from the monitoring cluster.

- Each node from the monitoring cluster should have this in its configuration:

  `marvel.agent.enabled: false`

Details about the two settings [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/marvel/current/configuration.html#stats-export).

Comment: These settings don't seem to work. I've added the following settng in config file 'marvel.agent.exporter.es.hosts: "localhost:9400"' on production cluster, but I can see that the marvel realted data is still gettng indexed on the production cluster. Do I need to do anything additonal ?